# How to search a table that has multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table with pagination and a search function that searches the said table.  At the moment the search function only searches for values on the table page I am on rather than the entire table.  Is there any way I can amend the search function below to allow the entire table to be searched?

Please note I am searching by multiple TD elements of the table so hence the multiple TD variables.

**TS File**

```
searchTable(table) {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, td2, td3, td4, i, txtValue, txtValue2, txtValue3, txtValue4;
input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById(table);
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
  td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
  td3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
  td4 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
  if (td || td2 || td3 || td4) {
    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
    txtValue2 = td2.textContent || td2.innerText;
    txtValue3 = td3.textContent || td3.innerText;
    txtValue4 = td4.textContent || td4.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValue2.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValue3.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValue4.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }       
 }
}
```

**Table**

```
 <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="customersTable">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Contact Email</th>
                            <th scope="col">Package</th>
                            <th scope="col">Subscription</th>
                            <th scope="col">Active</th>
                            <th scope="col">Customer Since</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let cust of customers | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
                            <td class="primaryColumn">
                                {{cust.name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.email.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.package_name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.subscription_name.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td [ngClass]="{
              'active' : cust.sub_status.BOOL == true,
              'inactive' : cust.sub_status.BOOL == false
           }">
                                {{cust.sub_status.BOOL}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{cust.date_created.S}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <div ngbDropdown placement="bottom-right">
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" ngbDropdownToggle>
                                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class=" dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="selectCustomer(cust);openForm(custUpdate)"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><span class="menu-option">Edit</span></a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="selectCustomer(cust);openForm(custDelete)"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i><span class="menu-option">Delete</span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**HTML File**

```
 <div class="form-group has-search">
            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="searchTable('customersTable')">
 </div>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: "only searches for values on the table page I am on rather than the entire table" - please elaborate. Where is "the entire table"? Is this a `<table>` generated using server-side code?

Comment: Sorry - it is not generated by server side code.  It is generated on the front end HTML using <table> <tr> <td> tags.  I'll add to my question above now.  But what I mean is that if there is 5 pages for the table where each page lists only 5 items - my search function will only search those 5 items from that page number that I am on.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: If the `<table>` is generated client-side, why not just search through the source data first (as that should be faster than reading `textContent`)? Also you don't need to do `textContent || td.innerText` anymore - even IE9 supported `textContent`.

Comment: As this is an Angular application, **you really shouldn't be using the DOM at all** - you should implement your search feature as a service or inside the relevant components.

Comment: And your `search` function isn't using type annotations, which defeats the point of using TypeScript. The code you've posted won't even compile with `tsc`'s current defaults as of TypeScript 3.0.

Comment: Not an answer but a feedback: Use should use a variable to hold the returned elements in `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")` and use that to get your other `td`s instead of searching them everytime.

Comment: Yeah it did feel like I was doing something wrong.  But yeah makes more sense now - thanks for that.  I'll review and go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pagination is done on the front-end side and since, as someone also stated in the comments section, this is an Angular application, **juggling with DOM is not the best practice**.

What you can do is use a work variable that would hold the current state of the `customers` list at any time and hold the data set in a different variable.

Table filtering would mean filtering the complete data set and assigning the result to the work variable. Angular should then detect the change and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.  Thanks for that.  I'll scrap what I have above with the search function and do it as per your suggestion above.